# Entity Framework Query for Complex Sql

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq-query-syntax

Anyone know how to represent this as an Entity Framework query?  Either method syntax or query syntax is fine.

```
Declare @UserId int = 18

Select *
From [Profiles]
Where [Profiles].[ProfileId] 
IN( Select [SecurityProfileAssignments].[ProfileId]
    From [SecurityProfileUsers]
    Join [SecurityProfileAssignments] On [SecurityProfileAssignments].[SecurityProfileId] = [SecurityProfileUsers].[SecurityProfileId]
    Where [SecurityProfileUsers].[UserId] = @UserId)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a variable userId:

```
from p in Profiles
join spa in SeucrityProfileAssignments
    on p.ProfileId equals spa.ProfileId
join spu in SecurityProfileUsers
    on spa.SecurityProfileId equals spu.SecurityProfileId
where spu.UserId = userId
select new //optional object type
{
    //values to select
}
```

Comment: Awesome!  Never thought to change the query!  Works like a champ thanks!